# Oracle DBMS_PROFILER only shows Anonymous in the results tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am new to DBMS_PROFILER. All the examples I have seen use a simple top-level procedure to demonstrate the use of the profiler, and from there get all the line numbers etc. I deploy all code in packages, and I am having great difficulty getting my profile session to populate the plsql_profiler_units with useful data. Most of my runs look like this:

```
RUNID RUN_COMMENT UNIT_OWNER  UNIT_NAME         SECS PERCEN
----- ----------- ----------- -------------- ------- ------
5     Test        <anonymous> <anonymous>        .00    2.1
      Profiler

5     Test        <anonymous> <anonymous>        .00    2.1
      Profiler

5     Test        <anonymous> <anonymous>        .00    2.1
      Profiler
```

I have just embedded the calls to the dbms_profiler.start_profiler, flush_data and stop_profiler as per all the examples. The main difference is that my code is in a package, and calls in to other package. Do you have to profile every single stored procedure in your call stack? If so that makes this tool a little useless!

I have checked http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_dbms_profiler.htm for hints, among other similar sites.

Comment: What database version ? It is possible that if the optimizing compiler is doing something like inlining code, it becomes impossible to reconcile measurements from the restructured optimized code against the original source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that this is not a problem with your query to retrieve data from `plsql_profiler_units`?

---

I tried this:

```
Create Procedure sub_procedure As
Begin
  dbms_output.put_line('test');
End;

Create Package test_package As
  Procedure test;
End;

Create Package Body test_package As
  Procedure test As Begin
    For i In 1 .. 10 Loop
      If(i<=5) Then
        sub_procedure;
      End If;
    End Loop;
  End;
End;

Begin
  DBMS_PROFILER.start_profiler(SYSDATE);
  test_package.test;
  DBMS_PROFILER.stop_profiler;
End;
```

and this simple query

```
Select uni.unit_name, dat.line#, dat.total_occur
  From plsql_profiler_data dat
  Join plsql_profiler_units uni On (     uni.runid = dat.runid
                                     And uni.unit_number = dat.unit_number )
```

gives me the expected result showing also packages and procedures:

```
<anonymous>    1  0
<anonymous>    2  0
<anonymous>    3  2
<anonymous>    4  1
<anonymous>    5  0
TEST_PACKAGE   2  0
TEST_PACKAGE   3 11
TEST_PACKAGE   4  5
TEST_PACKAGE   5  6
TEST_PACKAGE   8  1
SUB_PROCEDURE  1  0
SUB_PROCEDURE  3  5
SUB_PROCEDURE  4  5
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I ran your example and that worked ok. Then, I reran the package that was causing me trouble from SQL*Developer, and it seemed to profile OK. One thing I thought of is that my comment was not unique in my first test - does it have to be? Adding the timestamp looks like a good way to ensure that.

Comment: Ok, I still have the same problem when the stored procedure is called by my application, but it profiles OK when called from SQL*Developer. The application connects as a different user to the one I typically use from SQL*Developer - are there any permissions that need to be set in order for it to work properly?

Comment: @Greg Reynolds: It does not have to be unique. The `run_comment` parameter is stored in `plsql_profiler_runs.run_comment` and helps to distinguish different calls. Connect to *SQL*Developer* using the same user as your application to find out if grants are missing.

Comment: Yes - that was it - I changed the application to log in as the schema owner and everything was fine. Doh!